# How to Serve static Media Files in Django?

Tags: django

I'm beginner with Web Server Apache. I want to ask your guys how to Serve Media Files in Django.

I read this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/#serving-files

```
This example sets up Django at the site root, but serves robots.txt, favicon.ico, and anything in the /static/ and /media/ URL space as a static file. All other URLs will be served using mod_wsgi:

Alias /robots.txt /path/to/mysite.com/static/robots.txt
Alias /favicon.ico /path/to/mysite.com/static/favicon.ico

Alias /media/ /path/to/mysite.com/media/
Alias /static/ /path/to/mysite.com/static/

<Directory /path/to/mysite.com/static>
Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /path/to/mysite.com/media>
Require all granted
</Directory>

WSGIScriptAlias / /path/to/mysite.com/mysite/wsgi.py

<Directory /path/to/mysite.com/mysite>
<Files wsgi.py>
Require all granted
</Files>
</Directory>
If you are using a version of Apache older than 2.4, replace Require all granted with Allow from all and also add the line Order deny,allow above it.
```

I ask Web Server supporter, they said my server have supported mode mod_wsgi already and they said to me that I can config it in **.htaccess**. But I really have no knowledge about this. Please help me rewrite URL:

Rewrite URL **`mydomain.com/served/`** to folder with path **`/home/mydomain.com/public_html/media`**. All files in **`/home/mydomain.com/public_html/media/filename.jpg`** will access with **`mydomain.com/served/`**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just be able to use the `Alias` directive to alias `/served/` to the media folder in question. So for example:

```
Alias /served/ /home/example.com/public_html/media/
```

That would mean that a request to `http://example.com/served/filename.jpg` will map through to `/home/example.com/public_html/media/filename.jpg`. You can do a similar thing for resources in `/static/`.

(Note that the example above uses `example.com` rather than `mydomain.com` due to [SO restrictions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208963/why-are-certain-example-urls-like-http-site-com-and-http-mysite-com-blocke).)